# Change list to integer in R

Tags: r, list, integer

Hel lo everyone I would need help in order to change my output into a new king of integer

Here is what I have :

```
> cluster$clusters
[[1]]
[1] "Cluster1" "Cluster6" "Cluster15" "Cluster14" "Cluster13"

[[2]]
[1] "Cluster2" "Cluster7" "Cluster8" "Cluster12"

[[3]]
[1] "Cluster3" "Cluster8"

[[4]]
[1] "Cluster4" "Cluster9"

[[5]]
[1] "Cluster5" "Cluster10" "Cluster11"
```

adn I would like to change it to an integer such as :

```
> cut_avg
Cluster1 Cluster6 Cluster15 Cluster14 Cluster13 Cluster2 Cluster7 Cluster8 Cluster12 Cluster3 
       1        1         1         1         1        2        2        2         2        3

Cluster8 Cluster4 Cluster9  Cluster5  Cluster10   Cluster11 
       3        4        4         5          5          5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rep` to repeat the index of list for their respective length times.

```
x <- cluster$clusters
cut_avg <- setNames(rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x)), unlist(x))
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not get the Cluster names above the cluster group number where there are